# Assigning the value of a formula to a variable with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am currently learning Python in order to create excel files in an automatic way.
However I got some troubles with the conditional formatting part of the **openpyxl** library.

Here is the piece of code that does not work :

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
red_color = "ffc7ce"
red_color_font = "9c0103"
red_font = xl.styles.fonts.Font(size=14, bold=True, color=red_color_font)
red_fill = xl.styles.fills.PatternFill(start_color=red_color, end_color=red_color, fill_type="solid")
#------
for i in range(3,131,1):
        ws["B"+str(i)] = "=SUM(C{}:D{})".format(str(i),str(i))
        ws["C"+str(i)] = 0
        ws["D"+str(i)] = 0
        ws["E"+str(i)] = "=SUM(F{}:G{})".format(str(i),str(i))
        ws["F"+str(i)] = 0
        ws["G"+str(i)] = 0
        # conditional formating - putting red cells if second applications have been forgotten
        if i==4:
            threshold = [str(int(ws["B"+str(i-1)].value))]
            ws.conditional_formatting.add("B4",xl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="lessThan",formula=threshold,fill=red_fill,font=red_font))
        if i>=5:
            threshold = [str(int(ws["B"+str(i-1)].value)-int(ws["B"+str(i-2)].value))]
            ws.conditional_formatting.add("B{}".format(str(i)),xl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator="lessThan",formula=threshold,fill=red_fill,font=red_font))
```

As you can see it, the problem comes from the *threshold* variable.
When I run the code, I get the following error message :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '=SUM(C3:D3)'
```

Does someone know how it is possible to extract the value from the formula used for the B column ?

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the excel has been opened. In your case, it looks like the excel is generated by you from python, then there is no evaluated value stored in the excel.

What you can do:

A. Since you generate the code in python, you know what value are assigned to those cells. You don't need to read those values back from excel. You can create a dataframe to store the structure and if you want to see the value of C[3], then call df['C'].iloc[3]

B. Before trying to access the evaluated value of a cell, you need to open the excel and save it. This way, Mircosoft Excel will save information on both the formula and the evaluated value of that cell. Then, you can read back the excel in your python code. More specifically, you can read in both the formula and value of a cell:

```
wb_values = load_workbook(path_xlsx+wb_name,data_only=True)
wb_formulas = load_workbook(path_xlsx+wb_name)
```